# Ubuntu 14.04 Disable automatic network connection until after login

Tags: wireless, 14.04, networking, login

So I recently connected to my university's network for the first time using Ubuntu. After configuring it to correctly work with PEAP, it will now prompt me to login using my credentials on the login screen. The credentials are stored somewhere within my user account - once I log in to my account Ubuntu will automatically connect seamlessly to the network.

How do I disable this prompt from appearing on the login screen? It always seems to pop up right as I am trying to type in the last few characters of my password and throws me off. I still want to have Ubuntu automatically connect to the network once I have logged in.

Comment: I do not know if I set that up. Ill check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable *All users may connect to this network* when creating a network profile, then that profile is always available, even if no one's logged in. And Network Manager will try to connect to it even before you log in. If you disable it, it will only connect when you log in. This has the effect that no other users (logged in or not) can connect to it if you are not logged in.

[image]

<sup><sub>Sometime in the distant past, the text was "Available to all users", I believe, but that seems to have changed.</sub></sup>