# Disable automatic network connection until after login

Tags: networking, login

My question is identical to what was asked in "[Ubuntu 14.04 Disable automatic network connection until after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516406/ubuntu-14-04-disable-automatic-network-connection-until-after-login)".

However, the answer accepted there does not answer my question as it suggests to disable the automatic connection to a WLAN completely, whereas I am interested in **just suppressing (delaying) the automatic connection until after I have logged in** so that I do not get prompted to enter the WLAN password.